# How to calculate time complexity when two iteration involved with different inputs?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Merge the ranges given in the input.

Input: (0,1) (3,5), (4,8), (10,12),(9,10)

Output: (0, 1), (3,8), (9,12)

Code:

step 1: sort(input) - nlogn

create an array whose length is the last number after sorting. In the above ex, it is 12.

step 2:

```
int tupleCounter = 0;
        for(Tuple tuple : tuples){
            for(int i=tuple.first; i<=tuple.second; i++){
                if(period[i] != -1){
                    tupleCounter = period[i];
                }
                period[i] = tupleCounter;
            }
            tupleCounter ++;
        }
```

Output of the above block: [0,0,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]

step 3: split them and show the output.

How to calculate the time complexity of step 2 ? Outer loop runs as per the size of the input, which is N and inner loop runs based on the value in the each section which is ultimately the length of the array(m).

So the time complexity of the step 2 is O(n + m). Am I correct?

Comment: Nested for loops multiply together not add

Comment: are you suggesting the answer is O(nm)? But this means, each iteration in outer loop has m iterations. But that is not the case rite? The number of iteration in the inner loop depends on the value in the tuple.

Comment: When you are looking at complexity in O( ) notation you want to look at the worst case.  Consider the case where the difference of the values in each tuple is the same as the length of the list of tuples.

Comment: you mean [(0,12),(0,12),(0,12),(0,12)].? Then it is O(nm). Am I correct?

Comment: It is always O(mn)